# PHP profiling with microtime(): Negative time?

Tags: php, microtime

For a very simple profiling I use `microtime()` like this:

```
$now = microtime();
for (...) {
    // do something
    echo microtime() - $now;
    $now = microtime();
}
```

Now, the output of the `echo` line seems completely random, that is, I expected fluctuations, but I *didn't* expect *negative numbers* showing up.

However, a typical result contains ~ 1/3 negative numbers. I confirmed this on Solaris (PHP 5.0.x) and WinVista (PHP 5.2.3).

What the heck is going on here? Have I invented accidently a time machine?

Comment: Yes U have!!!!! :) Let me know to control it....

Comment: this is something i noticed too but never bothered investigating, i'm curious for the anwser :)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you want to do operations on what is returned by microtime, you have to set the "get as float" parameter to true (it defaults to false).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

```
$now = microtime(true);
for (...) {
    // do something
    echo microtime(true) - $now;
    $now = microtime(true);
}
```

Comment: Yes, yes. Reading the documentation sometimes helps. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: To complete Arkh's answer: The response of `microtime()` without `get_as_float` is the *string* `sprintf('%f %d', $microseconds, time())`. Under what circumstances will anyone ever need this representation?