# PHP script... goes back in time?

Tags: php, microtime

Not really, but I am running into an issue where once in a blue moon while running this script, my time results in a negative number. here is the part of the script where it is happening:

```
public function execute()
{
    $time1 = microtime();
    foreach($this->tables as $table)
    {
        if($this->buildQuery($table))
        {
            if($this->submitQuery($table))
            {
                $time2 = microtime() - $time1;
                echo "Sync Successful({$time2}s).. $table <br /> \n";
                //log
            }
        }
        else echo "No data to sync in $table";
    }    
}
```

As you would suspect.. there should be nothing wrong with subtracting second time from the first and getting a rough estimate of how long the process took.. However.. If I run it enough times, sometimes the results will print out the following:

```
Sync Successful(0.062936s).. users
Sync Successful(-0.86901s).. profile
Sync Successful(-0.798774s).. groups
Sync Successful(-0.718851s).. phonebook
Sync Successful(-0.711768s).. products
No data to sync in locations
```

This is very rare, but this is an exact output of my last result. So my questions would be:

**How is this possible?** resulting in a 'negative' when this should clearly should not happen..

**What can I do to avoid this?** Is there a better way to go about this? Is `microtime()` unreliable?

**Can someone lend me a 1981 DeLorean DMC-12 capable of 88 mp/h?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP profiling with microtime(): Negative time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607150/php-profiling-with-microtime-negative-time)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You’re assuming the wrong data type. The [manual page of `microtime`](http://php.net/microtime) reads:

> By default, `microtime()` returns a string in the form "`msec sec`" […]

So you’re actually subtracting only the *msec* values as both [strings are converted to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) before the actual subtraction takes place.

Use `microtime(true)` to get float values:

> If *get_as_float* is set to TRUE, then `microtime()` returns a float […]

Comment: One of those wonderful design decisions in PHP that really make the language such a joy to use.